# MySQL issue using Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

OK so I made a mysql database on godaddy.com
I made an admin table there with 3 fields, ID,Username and Password.

In my program I connected to the database and it shows me the tables so I know its connected(Netbeans)

I downloaded Java JDBC driver and put it in the library of my project.
However when I run the program I get this error:

```
package testdata;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class TestData {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {
    String Name = "rsg";
         String Pass= "dfgd";
        String Host = "blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( Host,Name, Pass);

          Statement stmt = con.createStatement (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

        String query="DELETE FROM ADMIN";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM ADMIN";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


         rs.moveToInsertRow( );

        rs.updateInt("ID", 1 );
        rs.updateString("Username", "CHRIS");
        rs.updateString("Password", "CHRIS");        

         stmt.close();
         rs.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

error is:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ****THIS IS MY HostName****
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at testdata.TestData.main(TestData.java:28)
```

Comment: Hey @Steven, you better change your username and password. Never, ***ever*** put your real credentials in a public forum.

Comment: Its just a test, they wont be our real ones :)

Answer (score 0):

add mysql conntector jar file in your classpath.

Comment: I tried that just there. no difference. Added it to the src folder

Comment: roght click on project then click properties and then buildpath.after that click add jar button and select mysql jar

Answer (score 0):

I thing it's an issue with your host address. Check how should it look in MySql documentation

Comment: the host address is working, I just didn't want to share it with everyone with my user and password :P

Comment: Is line 28 this: "Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( Host,Name, Pass);"? If so, then it's obvious there's something wrong with address. Could you tell me which line is 28?

Comment: Yes that is line 28, Im using the same hostname as I did when adding the database in services? The database tables show up for me?

Comment: But driver host isn't only url for your database. Im not an expert in this things but when I used JDBC (actually I was using PostgreSql) my host address was looking something like ("jdbc:postgresql:testdb"). It differs in every database so that's why Im saying you should check in MySql's documentation how it's JDBC host address looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC connection string is not correct (you cannot simply use the hostname). You need to use a JDBC URL, which for MySQL takes the form:

```
"jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:<port>/<database>"
```

Where `<port>` is optional if your server is running on the default, and  is also optional. Change your `getConnection` method to this:

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format(
        "jdbc:mysql://%s:%s/%s", Host, "3306", "YourDBName"),
        Name, Pass);
```

Replace "YourDBName" with the name of the database you are trying to connect to. You also need to have the [MySQL driver JAR](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in your classpath.

Comment: What about the username and password for connecting to the database? do you not need this? Thanks!

Comment: @Steven - yes you do. They are included in the example I showed.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DatabaseUrl, DataDaseusername, DatabasePass);
```

example for `DatabaseUrl` is given below

jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.100/databasename

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)

Comment: make sure you added mysql connector jar file(eg:-mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar) in your project file and used Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); in your code

Comment: No still getting the error. I dont know what could be the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

**mysql-connector-java-5.1.22** download from [mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

Insure you have add the jar folder in your project.

I believe its is looking for `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

make  sure your connection string is correct  for an example `"jdbc:mysql://remot-example-mysql999.servage.net:3306/databasename?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";`